# Architecture Independent C Code

Tags: c

Can anyone suggest me how can I write a platform independent C code. The code should work properly irrespective of whether it is a 32 bit or 64 bit system/compiler. Is there any compiler which provides me this feature ? OR what are the things which I should take care while writing these kind of code?

Comment: Your question is too broad - there's no real way to answer it accurately if at all in this format.  Entire books could be written on how to do what you're asking.

Comment: "Is there any compiler which provides me this feature?" - a compiler is platform-dependent **by definition** (i.e., when a compiler is implemented, it is designated for a specific platform).

Comment: If you are asking about platform independent *code*, then C is already platform independent if you stick to the standard.

Comment: [How to write portable code in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3103568/995714), [Writing a portable C program - which things to consider?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2303516/995714), [Why is it difficult to write portable C programs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1257923/995714)

Comment: This is no small topic. There are hundreds of dirty details in the C language itself that you need to be aware of in order to write such code properly. In other words, you need to be a veteran C programmer.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Please don't encourage these kind of questions by digging up old trash. All those posts are not suitable for SO any longer: too broad and too opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

If the **code should be able to be compiled** on x86 and amd64 there shouldn't be too much of a problem (given a *hosted* environment) when you write proper code that adheres to the standard and doesn't use hardware-specific features.
Even more if you are lucky you can assume to have a POSIX-environment. If that's the case you should have (almost) no problems programming portable code.

However if you want your **binary to run on multiple architectures** you need to restrict yourself to compiling to a binary that uses the smallest common set of instructions shared by the ISAs you compile for. This won't work for ARM & x86 but you should be able to run x86 programs just fine on amd64 as amd64 are extensions.

You could however compile your code for multiple architectures and write a wrapper script that detects the architecture and launches the corresponding binary if that's feasible.

Answer (score -2):

C in itself if platform dependent because it compiles the code to machine's CPU's instruction set. You cannot create a compiled C executable that would run on different platforms but you can definitely write platform independent C code. You'll need to use functionalities of frameworks which provided this feature.

One such framework which I've used is the [Qt Framework](https://www.qt.io/). You write your logic utilizing Qt's features instead of language's default features such as file read/write, network access, creating UI components etc.

Comment: "_C in itself if platform dependent_" No, C is platform independent. Just like C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11810542/2703418 It's just that OS's like Linux and Windows have different libraries they offer for the OS.